# Perform Cron Job using PHP once

Tags: php, cron

I am doing a game, and I have to make a cron job, which will execute another PHP file after 60 seconds once only, how can i perform that using PHP?

Comment: Why make a cronjob when you only need to execute it once?

Comment: I need to execute it once but after 60 seconds, that's the important part :( I dont know how to execute a file after 60 seconds, how to make that task.

Comment: If max script execution time is high you can simply use `sleep(60)`.

Comment: When you say 'after 60 seconds', what is it that you're running it after?  Is this some sort of countdown thats triggered etc?  Knowing what you are working on overall will help us offer solutions much better.

Comment: I will create a row in database, after 60 seconds if nothing will change, that row will be deleted.

Comment: Make a `setTimeout` function in javascript and after 60 seconds make an ajax requets.

Comment: If i make setTimeOut, and the user exits the page, the row will not be deleted after 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use `at` instead of `cron` for such jobs (that is if you can't do it inside your script anyway)

The at command schedules a command to be run once at a particular time

Comment: Just google for `unix at command` or run `man at` in a linux terminal for a more dry manual page -- You can use the same trick for any unix/linux command